# Translation of "hear from you"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais

What would be a good translation of "Nice to hear from you again!" or "I hope to hear from you soon!"? I'm not sure whether the word "hear" should be directly translated as "entendre". In that case, the translations would be

> C'est bon d'entendre de vous de nouveau!

and

> J'espère entendre de vous bientôt!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't translate it this way, it's:

> C'est bon d'avoir de vos nouvelles !

... and:

> J'espère avoir de vos nouvelles bientôt !
>
> En espérant avoir de vos nouvelles bientôt !